# Enable soft keyboard in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using `Android Emulator v27.0.5`. I've created `Nexus 5` device with all **default settings** using `Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image` **API 19** `r33`. Everything is running fine but it takes input from Keyboard (h/w). I want to know how can I enable **soft keyboard** in emulator.
[image: Android Nexus 5 Kitkat Emulator]
It also has `Keyboard Input Enabled` in **Setting** window.
[image: Setting window]
By disabling `Hardware physical keyboard` at `Setting (Android OS one) -> Language & input -> Keyboard & Input Methods ->` it works! Thanks @JingJoeH 
[image: Keyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Enable keyboard Input" It's mean enable input from your computer's keyboard. For enable soft keyboard please check input setting in emulator
at Setting -> System -> Language & input -> Physical keyboard and turn on "Show virtual keyboard"